# Xcode 9.0, type react-native run-ios run failed

Tags: iphone, xcode, react-native

Xcode 9.0, type react-native run-ios run failed.

Yesterday, I type `react-native run-ios`, the iPhone Simulator will be launched.
This morning, I upgrade the Xcode8 to Xcode9. Now, I type `react-native run-ios`, the iPhone Simulator won't be launched. 
This error show:

> The following build commands failed:

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/yianwork/APP/yianGit/RN_doctor/source/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SDWebImage.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage\ iOS\ static.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView+WebCache.o

SDWebImage/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImageView+WebCache.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

(1 failure)

`node_modules` `react`'s `package.json` :

```
{
  "_from": "react@16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "_id": "react@16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha1-LMsa+0QlzMEveKEjpmby5MFBrbk=",
  "_location": "/react",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "version",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "react@16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "name": "react",
    "escapedName": "react",
    "rawSpec": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
```

`node_modules` `react-native`'s `package.json` :

```
"_from": "react-native@^0.43.3",
  "_id": "react-native@0.43.4",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha1-kvtpN6tBWy5WEoNak6YYRd6Y600=",
  "_location": "/react-native",
  "_phantomChildren": {
    "babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties": "6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name": "6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "6.24.1",
    "inflight": "1.0.6",
    "inherits": "2.0.3",
    "minimatch": "3.0.4",
    "once": "1.4.0",
    "path-is-absolute": "1.0.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "1.0.4"
  },
```

When I using the Xcode and run the Simulator, the Simulator run well, but two Simulators run then. A Simulator is `iphone 6 iOS 9.0` and the other 　is `iphone 6 iOS 11.0`.

Comment: Try cleaning the build. Just throwing ideas around to see which sticks. Product > Clean

Comment: @ChiamakaNwolisa   Thank you.  Your comment as the answer.

Comment: I changed Xcode 9 to Xcode 8. I solved it.